# Java ArrayList overwrite

Tags: java, arraylist

A simple question: I store some values at an ArrayList at specific positions (indexes). These values are frequently updated by the code. My question is, in order to keep the ArrayList updated, it is sufficient to add the new value at the proper index (i.e. this action overwrites the older value stored there?) or do I have to remove first that value stored in that position of the ArrayList and then add the new value at this (now empty) position in the ArrayList?

Comment: As opposed to `list.get(i).setXXX(...);`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) says...

> **set**
>  public E set(int index,
>       E element) 
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element. 
> **Specified by:** set in interface
>   List 
> **Overrides:** set in class AbstractList 
> **Parameters:** 
> index -
>   index of the element to replace
>  element - element to be stored at the
>   specified position 
> **Returns:** the element previously at the specified
>   position 
> **Throws:** IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of
>   range (index < 0 || index >= size())

So, basically, you can simply override the value at a specific location...

You may also want to take a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: @PaulHicks Yeah, I was going for subtle... ;)

Comment: @PaulHicks     Sorry, I got confused! I don't want to use Set, I have to use ArrayList. Does ArrayList presents same behavior as Set, i.e. the operation "add" overwrites the existing element stored at the specified index?

Comment: @Kotsos Yes.  `ArrayList` is a descent of `List`, so it has `set`.  This method is, infact, implemented by `ArrayList` directly, for it's required purposes.